# Universal Link works in Safari browser, but not in Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ios-universal-links

I am testing on `IOS 15.5` and `IOS16.4.1`.

**1. Add the code to Info.plist and**

```
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string> Bundle ID </string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string> myScheme </string>
    </array>
```

**2. Add Associated Domain**.

**3. Make AASA file and upload server(path : .well-known/applep-app-site-association)**.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "<TeamID>.<Bundle ID>",
        "paths": [ "/test/connect.asp" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this way, the universal link runs normally in the safari browser.

But it doesn't work in chrome browser. I don't know if there is a setting that needs to be added or if chrome doesn't support universal links anymore, thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution on this?

Comment: Apple only supports Safari browser. So I also implemented the `app schema` so that it can be used in most browsers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide any link here,thanks.

Comment: @UsamaYousaf I hope you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

`apple` no longer provides `universal link` for browsers other than safari.
So I implemented both `url sheme` and `universial link`. `universial link` was written in the question, so please refer to the question.

**1. Register url scheme**.

- xcode -> project -> target -> info -> URL Types.
  [image]

  **2. sheme processing**

```
let url = URL(string: "yourUrlSheme:Vacation?index=1")


UIApplication.shared.open(url!) { (result) in
    if result {
       // The URL was delivered successfully!
    }
}
```

See the article below for details.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app